# how to calculate the position from right side of the screen so that the entire window is always shown on the screen

Tags: macos, applescript

I am currently using Applescript to calculate the size and position of a window from left to right which works great. Here is an example where I am trying to position of a window as "Left half of the screen"

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Xcode"
        activate
        tell window 1 to set size to {(1600) / 2, 814}
        tell window 1 to set position to {0, 0}
    end tell
end tell
```

I am trying to work on positioning of the window "Right half of the screen" (technically I can calculate this by setting the X = screenWidth/2 but the issue is, the window of Xcode app some part of the screen is not visible the user where as if I calculate it from right I can ensure the entire window is on the screen visible to the user.

Actual result: [https://share.cleanshot.com/COYgKD](https://share.cleanshot.com/bXpnQU)

Expected result: https://share.cleanshot.com/BIELCA

Goal: Show right half of the window that ensure the entire window is on the screen visible to the user

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What are the values of `screenWidth` and the position and size of the window in the images?

Comment: How about `x = screenWidth - windowWidth`?

Comment: What are your display's pixel dimensions? Your chrome window obviously takes up more than half of the screen. Also, you can't position a window above the menu bar so ideally, you should take that into account in your vertical calculations. Also, on retina displays, you may need to halve the numbers that you use. Finally, why do you have this inside two tell blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain your your screen's dimensions:

```
tell application id "com.apple.finder" to set ¬
        [null, null, screenW, screenH] to the ¬
        bounds of the desktop's window
```

XCode is scriptable, I believe, so there's no need to invoke System Events to get or set its size and position.  However, scriptable application windows offer this by way of the `bounds` property just like the `desktop's window` above:

```
tell application id "com.apple.Xcode" to tell ¬
    window 1 to tell (a reference to its bounds)
    set [X, Y, W, H] to its contents
    set || to W - screenW
    
    set its contents to [X - ||, Y, W - ||, H]
end tell
```

This will right-align the window flush with the right edge of the screen, even if it's already fully visible on your screen.  To have it only effect the move if it's required, then insert a condition such that **`|| > 0`**.

---

The following is a functionally identical version of the last code block, but utilising statements that are formulated in a more explicit manner:

```
tell application id "com.apple.Xcode" to tell ¬
    the front window to if (it exists) then
    set [X, Y, W, H] to the bounds
    set || to W - screenW
    set the bounds to [X - ||, Y, W - ||, H]
end tell
```

I added a check to make sure the `front window` (which is identical to and equivalent terminology for `window 1`) exists, so in cases where there are no windows, the script won't throw an error.

Here, the `bounds` property is explicitly accessed *by value* whenever we need to retrieve or set its value, compared to the version above where the property was being accessed *by reference*.  In this situation, there's no tangible difference between the two methods.

Comment: from what I understand use contents for scriptable apps and for non scriptable use size/position? @cjk

Comment: No, it's not about their scriptability, it's about how the object hierarchy.  `size` and `position` are properties of `window` class objects that are children of _System Events_'s `process` elements, which was the case in your original script.  This applies to all apps, as it's bypassing any scriptable interface and simply hacking the UI to manipulate on-screen elements.  However, for apps that _are_ scriptable, then scripting it is infinitely better.  The `window` class objects that are owned by the `application` parent element (like in my script) have the `bounds` property.

Comment: `contents` has nothing to do with this, but relates to the my use of **`(a reference to...)`**, which retrieves a reference (or pointer) to the `bounds` property rather than evaluating it straight away.  Calling `contents` the forces the dereferencing of the property, and returns its value (when it's being read), or returns an insertion pointer (when we want to set the property to a new value).  Perhaps I shouldn't have written the solution so opaquely.  I'll add a version that's functionally identical but clearer in how it operates.